# How do you show an ampersand in TdxBarButton text

Tags: devexpress

I have a TdxBarButton that has text that contains an ampersand and I need to display the ampersand. I do not need to have a hotkey, in fact I must not have a hotkey.

How do I disable the hotkey and display the ampersand?

Also, if anyone could give me a link to the TdxBarButton documentation it would be great.

Comment: Escape the ampersand by doubling it, as in `Test && Test Again`. This is standard Windows behavior, and has nothing to do with TdxBarButton specifically.  Asking for the docs link is off-topic here. You'll find it on the DevEx site. A useful search expression for Google might be `tdxbarbutton documentation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "& amp;" should do the work.(Do not add the quotes and space)
So this is how ur text would look like - 'Test && Test Again'